# Generic argument 'extends' multiple classes

Tags: java, generics

I have a question about generic arguments, this is the code I have:

```
public <T extends Renderable, Box> void setBackBox(T bb) {
    ...
}
```

As you see you can give as parameter bb an object that extends Box & Renderable.
But eclipse gives the following waring: 'The type parameter Box is hiding the type Box'.

How can I fix this/work around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, you're defining two type-parameters:

- `T extends Renderable`
- `Box`

`Box` is the alias of the second method-scoped type-parameter and if you have another one with the same name (class-scoped), the method-scoped one will hide it. That's why Eclipse throws a warning.

If you want `T` to extend both `Renderable` and `Box`, you have to do:

```
public <T extends Renderable & Box> void setBackBox(T bb)
```

Also note that when your type-parameter(s) extend multiple types, you're allowed to use **one class**, which has to be first in the list. For example, if `Box` is a class, the correct definition would be:

```
public <T extends Box & Renderable> void setBackBox(T bb)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here you defined Box to be a generic type parameter, which hides the `Box` class/interface :

```
public <T extends Renderable, Box> void setBackBox(T bb)
```

If Box is an interface that should be a bound of T :

```
public <T extends Renderable & Box> void setBackBox(T bb)
```

If Box is a class that should be a bound of T :

```
public <T extends Box & Renderable> void setBackBox(T bb)
```

If both Box and Renderable are classes, they can't both be type bounds of T. Only the first type bound can be a class.