# How to solve a Java generics issue at runtime for an Either.converge() method

Tags: java, generics

**UPDATE:** Thanks to [rzwitserloot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) answer, I am in total agreement that my original attempted solution via reflection is terrible and should be avoided.

After exploring the static method solution included in rzwitserloot's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77461945/501113), I've now moved to this solution:

```java
public <T> T converge() {
  return (T) converge(this);
}

public static <T> T converge(Either<? extends T, ? extends T> either) {
  return either.left.isPresent()
      ? either.left.get()
      : either.right.get();
}
```

---

Given this severely shortened `Either` class (the [full version](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/8b5116dbc2957cfea22032924935f10e) on GitHub with full javadocs)...

```java
public final class Either<L, R> {
  private final Optional<L> left;
  private final Optional<R> right;

  public Either(Optional<L> left, Optional<R> right) {
    if (left.isEmpty() == right.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("left.isEmpty() must not be equal to right.isEmpty()");
    }
    this.left = left.map(Objects::requireNonNull);
    this.right = right.map(Objects::requireNonNull);;
  }

  public <T> T converge(
      Function<? super L, ? extends T> leftFunction,
      Function<? super R, ? extends T> rightFunction
  ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(leftFunction);
    Objects.requireNonNull(rightFunction);

    return this.right
        .<T>map(r -> Objects.requireNonNull(rightFunction.apply(r)))
        .orElseGet(() ->
            this.left
                .map(l -> Objects.requireNonNull(leftFunction.apply(l)))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("should never get here")));
  }
}
```

I noticed that I was making the same call to `converge(Function.identity(), Function.identity())`, repeatedly:

```java
Either<Integer, Integer> either = ...;
//...
var t = either.converge(Function.identity(), Function.identity());
```

So, in the interest of DRYing (Don't Repeat Yourself) out the client code, I wanted to add a parameterless `converge()` function like this...

```java
public <T extends L & R> T convergeDesired() {
  return left.isPresent()
      ? left.get()
      : right.get();
}
```

This solution causes a compiler error, and seems to be thwarted by the Java generics issue [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829160/501113).

Because `R` can be a class, it breaks the generics rule of limiting extending `T` to a single class, which, if provided, must also be first. There is no way to know ahead of time if the `Either` is composed of two classes, or that `L` is an interface and `R` is a class.

The hacked solution (below) seems extremely fragile. I'm trying to understand what options there are, if any, to improve it to behave more like the `convergeDesired()` method defined above.

```java
public <T> Optional<T> convergeHacked() {
  return this.left.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass() ==
      this.right.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass()
      ? (Optional<T>) (this.left.isPresent()
          ? left.get()
          : right.get())
      : Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need some kind of `UnaryEither` (inspired by [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) which is a `Function<T, T>`).

Comment: @sp00m I don't follow. Could you be more specific? Or provide at least part of an example of how to apply it to improve the `convergeHacked()` method?

Comment: My eyes hurt from the abuse of these types. This is such a bad idea. Virtually none of the existing libraries work like this (does `java.util.Map.get` return `Optional` or `Either`? It does not. It never will.)

Comment: @rzwitserloot The current Java architects are now explicitly biased in moving towards FP style, which includes reducing and/or eliminating the use of `null` with proper types like `Optional` and `Either`. IOW, 2004 OOP called, and said to give back their `Map.get()`-returns-null-pattern.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium and if you explain how team OpenJDK is going to fix `java.util.Map.get` or point at discussion that they are even thinking about it, I will take that comment seriously. Until then, whether they are 'now explicitly biased in moving towards FP style' or not - the answer is clearly 'they are not' in regards to e.g. map.get.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium I believe sp00m is saying you'll need a `UnaryEither<T> extends Either<T, T>` class if you want a type-safe no-parameter `converge()` method that returns a single type (and this `converge()` method would only exist in the `UnaryEither` class, not the `Either` class).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on @rzwitserloot's Answer, if I could move to Vavr (https://www.vavr.io), I would do so and use their Scala-inspired `Option` instead of Java's insufficient `Optional`. Vavr hasn't reached a final 1.0 state, and remains in beta. Once it is out, I will likely flip most of my Java projects over to using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fragile? No, broken.

```
public <T> Optional<T> convergeHacked() {
  return this.left.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass() ==
      this.right.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass()
      ? (Optional<T>) (this.left.isPresent()
          ? left.get()
          : right.get())
      : Optional.empty();
}
```

Generics erasure is not some sort of middle finger to java programmers. It has a purpose and you can't get around it if only you toss enough reflection in there. It results in the above code which seems fine **but it does nothing at all**:

`this.left.getClass()` will return, obviously, `java.util.Optional`. Never any subtype of it - `Optional` is `final`!

Therefore `this.left.getClass().getTypeParameters[0]` will return an object representing `T`. **Literally**. Not what it actually is (you can't get around erasure, stop trying!) - the literal T. So, that whole if block is trivially useless - **it is always true**. It is simply impossible to write code for that to fail. You can and should try that - make an `Either` where the two types aren't homogenous and watch how that safety measure you added doesn't work at all.

### A sidetrack rant

All of this is a really bad idea. And your own code perhaps best explains why you should toss all this in the bin and stop being so scared of null pointers:

```
return this.left.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass() ==
      this.right.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getClass()
      ? (Optional<T>) (this.left.isPresent()
          ? left.get()
          : right.get())
      : Optional.empty(); // THIS LINE
}
```

That line never triggers (see previous section), but the intent is clear: You want a call to `.converge()` to just silently return an empty optional if the either isn't homogenous.

And that highlights everything that is wrong with this mindset. "When things aren't like you expect, silently do nothing" is a common effect of overuse of optionals (it's what happens when you call `.map` on an optional after all: If the optional is empty, nothing happens. Silently.)

an NPE points exactly at where a programmer messed up an assumption. It's one of those 1000 ducks and a horse questions, except this one does have an answer: What's better? 1 bug that takes 2 hours to fix, or 10 bugs that take 5 minutes each?

Objectively, there's only one correct answer to that question. You want the 10 bugs; you fix em in less than half the time, after all.

### The missing java feature you need to make this work

What you're effectively looking for is the concept of a homogenous either. That, or the most common shared subtype - given an `Either<Integer, Double> either;`, for example, you want `either.converge()` to be an expression of type `Number` (given that you don't know if it's a left-handed either or a right-handed one). Thus, you want to capture that notion.

Which you are trying with `<T extends L&R>` but javac won't let you declare that. Because java's generics were never meant to hack fundamentally culturally incompatible concepts<sup>1</sup> into java. Also, it's wrong. You want T to be the opposite! You're looking for `L extends T & R extends T` (isntead of `T extends L & T extends R` - though neither is valid java). Given e.g. `Either<Integer, Double>` you don't want a `T` that is both Integer and Double (no such type exist or can exist). You want a T such that both Integer and Double are that T (i.e. Number, or Object). i.e. `T super L & R`. Which still isn't valid java.

We have now arrived at something that is perhaps JEP-able (java enhancement proposal): There is no real reason `<T super L & R>` couldn't work. It's syntactically available (currently, that is a syntax error, i.e. it's free without breaking existing code to now define that it does mean something), and semantically there's no real problem here either. Object still trivially always 'works', and possibly something more specific would.

### `static` methods can do this though!

Weirdly, perhaps, this works fine:

```
public static <T> T converge(Either<? extends T, ? extends T> either) {
  if (either.left.isPresent()) return either.left.get();
  return either.right.get();
}
```

You can't use `.orElseGet`, but that code compiles with zero warnings and does *exactly* what you want:

```
var ei = new Either<Integer, Double>(Optional.empty(), Optional.of(5.5));
Number n = Either.converge(ei); // works, compiles, no warnings!
System.out.println("We got: " + n); // prints "We got: 5.5"
```

### Hackery?

You can always resort to this mess:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T converge() {
  if (left.isPresent()) return (T) left.get();
  return (T) right.get();
}
```

it 'works':

```
var ei = new Either<Integer, Double>(Optional.empty(), Optional.of(5.5));
Number n = ei.converge(); // works, compiles, no warnings!
System.out.println("We got: " + n); // prints "We got: 5.5"
```

unfortunately it 'works' a little too well:

```
var ei = new Either<Integer, Double>(Optional.empty(), Optional.of(5.5));
String n = ei.converge(); // works, compiles, no warnings... ???
System.out.println("We got: " + n); // throws a class cast exception
```

We *wanted* a compiler error here. Instead we get a runtime error only. Also, if you try to use `ei.converge()` as parameter to another method it won't type properly either.

There's no way I can think of to make this work without either breaking the type system or resorting to using a `static` method.

### A dedicated subtype

This is one way out:

```
class UnaryEither<T> extends Either<T, T> {
  public UnaryEither(Optional<T> left, Optional<T> right) {
    super(left, right);
  }

  public UnaryEither(Either<T, T> source) {
    super(source.left, source.right);
  }

  public T converge() {
    return this.converge(Function.identity(), Function.identity());
  }
}
```

... but I doubt it's what you're looking for; it requires callers to make their homogenous eithers explicitly with `new UnaryEither(...)`.

### A second java feature that could have made this work

Another JEP-able approach would be this syntax:

```
public <T> converge(Either<? extends T, ? extends T> this) { ... }
```

But that's not going to compile either. Having a fake first param named `this` is actually legal java, but it **must** be an exact match (`void foo(Either<L, R> this) {}` is valid - try it!). The parameter does absolutely nothing, doesn't count as a real parameter, and this language feature exists *only* so you can stick annotations onto the receiver. But, a JEP could expand on it just to let you bind typevars like this. A second potential java feature that is backwards compatible in all relevant ways which would help here, but doesn't (yet?) exist.

### But, really. Garbage bin.

If you write methods that take optionals as parameters, you're doing it wrong.

---

[1] Optional, Either, vavr, and all that jazz is fundamentally not java, because a ton of existing API out there should use it *if* that is to be how java is written (trivial example: `java.util.Map` has a `get()` method. Surely that method should return `Optional<V>` if this is how java is to be written). Except, you can't just change the signatures of existing APIs without declaring bankruptcy and starting fresh with java2. Which isn't going to happen, which means java will **never** be like this. Hence, all you're accomplishing is that your code base works one way, and the core libraries along with most of the deps your projects use work in another way. You've just increased the friction and learning curve. **Even if** (big if!) we presume that this style is somehow objectively superior, you haven't actually accomplished a superior codebase because it isn't a complete transformation and cannot ever be. At least, unless java2 really does happen or some future java release just outright breaks everything and rewrites e.g. `map.get` to return `Optional<T>`.

Comment: Disregarding the arrogant ranting nature of your reply, you have been very helpful. I appreciate your taking the time to write out the various solutions. I finally stumbled upon your "this mess" solution right after I posted, which got me past my runtime issue. And I like your compile-time solution using the static method. Awesome stuff! Again, tysvm!

Comment: BTW, I totally agree with you about not liking the reflection-based solution (which, as you pointed out, is fundamentally broken). That is what literally motivated me to post a question. I didn't like the hacked nature of it. I even named it so that it was clear it was hacky.

Comment: And we're going to fundamentally disagree about `Optional`. I come from a decade of Scala. I am going to leverage what I learned there in Java. It's too bad that the JDK architects didn't go all the way to the level of the Scala `Option` (or Haskell `Maybe`). I would very much prefer to entirely switch to Vavr (https://www.vavr.io) as my FP foundation in Java. I will if/when it finally matures to a full 1.0 release (still in a beta, very stable mind you, but still beta state).

Comment: As the saying goes, when in Rome, act like Romans. You can write 'java-style' python code. You can write erlang style PHP. You can just write your java variables `underscore_separated_style` instead of `camelCaseStyle` if you come from python and that is just more readable to you. But, don't. Almost all programmers I know would agree that this is bad. Objectively, there are reasons too: Needless increase in learning curve, hard to interop with others in the community. Which this approach is going to suffer from, _heavily_. But, you do you. I'm glad this answer has been of some use :)

Comment: Ah, you are part of that bureaucratic core of old Java heads that desire as little change as possible. Nulls are going out of style. Fluent FP is coming, and stylistically taking over. And keeping Java adaptive and fresh in the face of that will inevitably happen. And I am one of those on the left side of the FP and fluent style adoption curve. There is no stopping us. Just the slow bleed off of those holding on to the status quo: https://www.flickr.com/photos/jurgenappelo/5201275209

Comment: And you call _me_ arrogant, then use "There is no stopping us". sjeesh. Buy a mirror.

Comment: LOL! Yeah. It feels really good, doesn't it?! ;P